# Geocoding API traffic dropped but latency tripled?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

we have been using the Google Geocoding API for a long time without issue.  just recently we dramatically reduced our calls for various reasons.  you can see from this 30day graph (in blue):

[image: traffic]

but what is strange is that exactly as we did that, the latency tripled:

[image: median latency]

any ideas as to why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Address geocoding requests are considerably slower than reverse (latlng) geocoding requests or Place ID lookups.

What may have happened here is that previously your traffic was made up of mostly reverse geocoding requests which are faster, and now the request volume is lower but dominated by address geocoding requests which are slower.